# How to increase area of collision / impact effect

Tags: unity-game-engine

So for background I am trying to make my first game, its basically a 3d brick-breaker style game. My questions are more design related any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have created a collection of basic cubes that form a larger shape parented these to an empty game object. Then I have a sphere/ball that can collide with the cubes and destroy the cubes it comes in contact with as expected.

Now, what I was hoping to do is under different situations have the ball do more damage ie. destory more cubes. I have tried increasing the size of the ball - this works to some degree but depends on the angle of impact. I have also tried instantiating another sphere at the point of impact to trigger more collisions. This doesnt appear to have must effect.

I am sure there must be an obvious answer to this. How do I increase the "impact" area of the ball/sphere ? Is there a way to have it keep moving in the same direction until it has destroyed a number of cubes?

I have all collider materials set with bounce of 1.

Comment: From what I understand you need more cubes to fall or destroy.The ball you are using might be a sphere.When you click the sphere in the inspector increase the size of sphere collider using edit collider.This will help to increase the area of contact.Try it.

Comment: Thanks @zyonneo and Filip F, very helpful comments indeed! I'm actually using both approaches now, really making my life much easier!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about keeping the ball moving, but I have a solution for destroying multiple bricks at once. Since all spheres have a collider, you could use an OverlapSphere. This checks for all colliders in a sphere of certain radius.

```
private void DestroyMultiple(Vector3 hitBrickPosition)
{
    int radius = 4; //insert whatever radius you prefer
    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(hitBrickPosition, radius);
    foreach(Collider col in colliders)
    {
         Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, as @zyonneo said, you could increase the size of the ball's collider radius through `collider.radius`. However, this would increase the radius from the center of the ball, meaning it would destroy bricks before it even hit them. This could be circumvented by moving the pivot point as you increase the radius, but that's overly complex.